# config ip adrress of a network interface through ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, networking, terminal, ip, network-interface

I am trying to configure ip address of network interfaces through terminal in ubuntu systems. So far successfully changed the IP address and other things through editing the interface file in the directory /etc/network/interfaces.

Is there any possibilities in changing the ip address of the interface through terminal using commands like configuring ip address of the router.

Thanks,Mohan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a static ip using the cli without go to edit the interfaces files, you can use `nmcli` tool:

```
# nmcli con add type ethernet con-name static2 ifname eth0 ip4 192.168.1.5/24 gw4 192.168.1.1
```

in the event that you want to add a temporary static ip address you can use ifconfig:

```
# ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255
```